# Mosaico blocks not staying in place

Tags: civimail, custom-templates, mosaico

Mosaico has been loaded for use in CiviCRM 4.6.33 in a Drupal environment. However, when blocks are dragged to create a template they do not stay in place. Has anyone experienced anything similar and any idea what might be causing the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We've seen some major improvements in the 4.7.x version (Mosaico 2.0) [over the 4.6.x version] - if a client wishes to use Mosaico we do recommend moving them up the 4.7.x first;